# ReactNative - Display API Content only after authentication

Tags: react-native

I would like to start a basic React Native mobile app that will do the following :

1. Authenticate if User is allowed to Display the API.
2. Display the API into Table format.

Thanks

Comment: what is your question and code?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
 (async() => {
   const authRes = await fetch(authApi);
   const authData = await authRes.json();
   // check or get token
   if(data) {
    setIsAuthenticated(authData);
   }
   const res = await fetch(apiurl);
   const data = await res.json();
   
   if(data) {
    setApiData(data);
   }
 })()
 
}, [])

return (
 
   {isAuthenticated && (
    <Table data={apiData} />
   )
)
```

To create the table with the api data passed in prop checkout [this](https://www.positronx.io/react-native-table-component-tutorial-with-example/)